# Función que analice URL y devuelva objeto con las propiedades

Tags: javascript, json

Hola tengo que realizar un ejercicio en el que me dan una url por ejemplo `https://www.amazon.es/electronica/b?ie=UTF8&node=599370031` y hacer una funcion que me devuelva un objeto  con las siguientes propiedades: protocolo, hot, query y un array params. Tal que asi

```
{ "protocolo": "http", "host": "www.amazon.es", "path": "", "query": {""} }
```

```js
var loc = new URL("http://cv.uoc.edu/webapps/bustiaca/listMails.do?mailId=5848042_774330153&l=181_m4_250_01_t01");


console.log(loc.protocol); // => "http:"
console.log(loc.host);     // => "example.com:3000"
console.log(loc.hostname); // => "example.com"
console.log(loc.port);     // => "3000"
console.log(loc.pathname); // => "/pathname/"
console.log(loc.hash);     // => "#hash"
console.log(loc.search);   // => "?search=test"
```

He utilizado esta función pero no se como generar el objeto. Gracias.

Comment: Pues ya casi lo tienes, ¿qué problemas te da crear el objeto con los campos que quieres?

Comment: Hola, no se como crear el objeto con éstos campos, que me da como resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente tienes casi todo ya hecho, sólo te falta agruparlo en una función y crear el objeto:

```js
/**
  url {string}
*/
function getDataFromURL (url) {
  const loc = new URL(url);
  return {
    protocolo: loc.protocol,
    host: loc.hostname,
    path: loc.pathname,
    query: loc.search
  };
}

const resultado = getDataFromURL("http://cv.uoc.edu/webapps/bustiaca/listMails.do?mailId=5848042_774330153&l=181_m4_250_01_t01");
console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me has ayudado mucho.